# How to display an Ionic Menu from right to left instead of left to right?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6

I'm new to ionic v6, and I'm using the ion-menu-toggle component, however I haven't found a way to make the menu curtain appear from right to left instead of left to right as the default component works. Any idea how I can customize this behavior?

This image sums up what I don't want... I need the opposite:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to put the menu element on the right side or left side of the page, you can use `side` property as explained in the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu).

```
<ion-menu side="start">
```

or

```
<ion-menu side="end">
```

if you want the "contents" of the menu to be right to left instead of left to right, you can use `dir`, like this:

```
<ion-menu dir="rtl">
```

Comment: Only For complement the answer consider: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u7zbyf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample.component.html